# Passing callback to children, to update a different child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a Navbar (component), which changes slightly when a user logs in in a SignIn component. So, my app looks like this:

I have a state in App, with authenticated set to false as default. I then have a function, updatedAuthenticationEvent, which sets the value of the app state.

Ihave a NavBar component, which I pass in the value of Authenticated. The idea is that I change something on the navbar, if authenticated. That would be, dont show "Signin" and rather show "Sign Out". So when I sign in on my sign in component, the navbar changes.

I then have a few routes in my app, one of which is my Signin, which I attempt to pass my function to, as a callback.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authenticated: false
        }
    }

    updatedAuthenticationEvent(isAthenticated)
    {
        console.log('Called!');
        this.setState({authenticated: isAthenticated});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                    <Navbar authenticated={this.state.authenticated} />
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}  />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} changeState={this.updatedAuthenticationEvent} />                          
                    </div>
                </Router>
                <Footer />

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My SignIn component, actually wraps my sign in content.
But for now, I'm just trying to make something work.
So for now, all I am doing is that when the sign in component loads, set the Authenticated to true.

My goal though is to pass that prop to my LoginBox, which has all the logic, and my actual sign in method. But for now, I want this to work.

```
export default class SignIn extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.props.changeState(true);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
                <div className="col-lg-4">
                    <LoginBox changeState={this.props.changeState}  /> 
                </div>
            </div>   
        )
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: this.props.changeState is not a function

What do I need to change to achieve this? Signin box event, should effect the Navbar.

Comment: I would not recommend passing props from your root component to your grand  grand children,that will make your code messy, checkout react-redux, so you can manage your app state in a more scalable way

Comment: react-redux will allow you to connect to your app state without passing props that way you are  doing

Comment: Thanks guys... My plan was to see how to do it with props. and then start working out redux. Redux seems daunting to a novice... but really looks like the right way to go.

Comment: Oh ok, check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I will not recommend this, but here it is,
use the render prop from Router, so you can pass the callback for changeState directly

```
<Route path="/login" render={(props) => <Login {...props} changeState={this.updatedAuthenticationEvent}  />
```

then I would recommend change `componentWillMount` for `componentDidMount` in your `Login` Component

and finally

Use an arrow function for your `updatedAuthenticationEvent` callback like

```
updatedAuthenticationEvent = (isAthenticated) => {
       ....
}
```

So you do not have context problems when executing `changeState`

working [demo](https://jsbin.com/riciqabele/edit?js,output)